# Project geomap onto band of sphere

Tags: plotting, geometry, geographics, textures

A band surrounding a sphere could be plotted using the ParametricPlot3D function:

```
base=Block[{r=10,urange=15,vrange=1.5},
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{Cos[u], Sin[u], ((u+v)/r)}/Sqrt[1 + ((u+v)/r)^2]], 
   {u, -urange,urange},{v,-vrange,vrange}, 
 Mesh->None,MaxRecursion->5,Axes->False,Boxed->False]]
```

[image]

Now, I would like to project a global geomap, such as:
[image]

onto the spherical band above. I have tried the Texture function, but clearly it does not offer correct projection:

```
Block[{r=10,urange=15,vrange=1.5},
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{Cos[u], Sin[u], ((u+v)/r)}/Sqrt[1 + ((u+v)/r)^2]], {u, -urange,urange},{v,-vrange,vrange},
Mesh->None,MaxRecursion->5,Axes->False,Boxed->False,
TextureCoordinateScaling->False,
TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4/3,#5/5}&),
PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 10], Texture[map],Opacity[.9]]]]
```

[image]

The problem should be the TextureCoordinateFunction, however, I could not figure out the exact solution.
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Do you want to project it on a sphere and cut the band or do you want the whole map stretched on a band?

Comment: The former, project on a sphere and save only the banded region.

Answer (score 9):

- The key point is we need to **unitization** the spherical coordinate. `{φ/(2 π), -θ/π}`
- To illustrate the method,we change some parametric here: use `t=2` instead of `r=10`,use `vrange = 3` instead of `vrange = 1.5`.
- `Normalize` the mapping to unit-sphere.

```
t = 2;
f[u_, v_] = Normalize[{Cos[u], Sin[u], (u + v)/t}, Sqrt[# . #] &];
```

- calculate the spherical coordinate `{r, θ, φ}` functions according to the parametric`{u,v}`.

```
{r, θ, φ} = 
  ToSphericalCoordinates[{x, y, z}] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> f[u, v]] //
    FullSimplify;
```

- for convenience, we use `map` from the wolfram data.

```
map = GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Brown], 
    Polygon[GeoVariant[#, "SimplifiedArea"], CommonName[#]] & /@ 
     CountryData[]}, GeoBackground -> None];
```

- **unitization** and **rotate** the spherical coordinate `{θ,φ}` to get `{φ/(2 π), -θ/π}`. To illustrate the spherical coordinate, we also draw some meshs according to `{u,v}`.

```
urange = 15; vrange = 3; 
ParametricPlot3D[
 f[u, v], {u, -urange, urange}, {v, -vrange, vrange}, Mesh -> 8, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick,Cyan], 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, θ], 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, φ]}, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, u, 
    v}, {φ/(2 π), -θ/π}],
 PlotStyle -> Texture[map], PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

**Reply to comment**

[image: Take from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html]
The picture take from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html

```
Clear[map, urange, t,r, θ, φ];
map=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QRoH.jpg"];
t = 10;
f[u_, v_] = Normalize[{Cos[u], Sin[u], (u + v)/t}, Sqrt[# . #] &];
{r, θ, φ} = 
  ToSphericalCoordinates[{x, y, z}] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> f[u, v]] //
    FullSimplify;
urange = 15; vrange = 1.5;
ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, -urange, urange}, {v, -vrange, vrange}, 
 Mesh -> 8, MeshStyle -> Cyan, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, θ], 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, φ]}, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, {φ/(2 π), -θ/π}],
  PlotStyle -> Texture[map], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

**Appendix**

The example as below indicate the equivalence of **unitization** and `TextureCoordinateScaling -> True` for the simple unit sphere.

```
map = Graphics[{FaceForm[RandomColor[]], 
     CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ 
   CountryData[]]; nonscaling = 
 SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, 
     z, θ, φ}, {φ/(2 π), -θ/π}], TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 10], Texture[map]], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip"]
scaling = 
 SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, 
     z, θ, φ}, {φ, -θ}], 
  TextureCoordinateScaling -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 10], Texture[map]], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, the purpose here is to have the geomap projected to the correct position of the sphere, which is banded sampled.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I will try to digest the code. Meanwhile, is the code for the last figure missing?

Comment: @BaoxiangPan Please see the update.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is thought provoking!